# Download mailing list

Tags: email, plugin, mailinglist, mailing

I'm hoping this is a simple question to answer ...

How do I download an ExpressionEngine mailing list?

I can easily add emails to an existing or new mailing lists however I can not work out how to download a list (in a spreadsheet or similar).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the [query module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/query/index.html) in a template (or with a query directly to your database, of course).

Something simple like this should output what you need:

```
{exp:query sql="SELECT email FROM exp_mailing_list WHERE list_id = '1'"}
{email}
{/exp:query}
```

**EDIT**

To improve this furher, you could use the [Download Content plugin](https://github.com/EllisLab/download-content) like this:

```
{exp:download_content filename="list.csv"}
    {exp:query sql="SELECT email FROM exp_mailing_list WHERE list_id = '1'"}
    {email}
    {/exp:query}
{/exp:download_content}
```

This should make the list download as a CSV file which can open in Excel. You may need to tinker with the spacing a bit (like removing the tabs) so you don't get blank lines in the file.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks Jeremy! I just wish there was a better way to output the mailing list eg. Spreadsheet.

Comment: Just posted an edit that should help.

Comment: For posterity's sake, some additional tips on generating spreadsheets can also be found in [What is the best method for exporting channel entries as a spreadsheet?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/q/515/22). I've found that it can even be as simple as outputting an html table, saving the webpage, and then opening with Excel.

Comment: That's awesome, thanks heaps for the edit @JeremyGimbel! It's greatly appreciated!