# Exporting Channel Entries on EEv1

Tags: channel-entries, import, export

I'm currently trying to export channel entry data from a version 1 ExpressionEngine site, v1.6.9 to be exact.

Can anybody tell me what the best way of doing this would be, Looking around a lot of modules on devot-ee etc seem to be ExpressionEngine v2 specific.

Thank You

Adam

Comment: Hi Adam, there are some good answers on this question: [What is the best method for exporting channel entries as a spreadsheet?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/515/what-is-the-best-method-for-exporting-channel-entries-as-a-spreadsheet). No add-on needed and independent of EE version.

Comment: @Alex Kendrick Thanks for the response and link Alex, have managed to find a solution below

Answer (score 2):

I have ended up going with the following plugin found on devot-ee

[Weblog Entries Exporter](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/weblog-entries-exporter)

Seemed to do the trick. Specifically for ExpressionEnginev1 it gives the option of exporting as a .CSV or .XML. Just what I needed