# Download to Excel or csv solutions

Tags: export

We need to get download functionality where channel entries can be downloaded to an Excel spreadsheet (preferably) or a csv at a push.

Been looking at Export_It and using it which is ok but ran into two problems which apparently are not solvable - at least have never got any results investigating them - so need maybe another solution.

The problems in question were/are:

1) Strange characters in the spreadsheet if the file contains accented foreign characters. I believe integrating PhpExcel with Export_It should fix this but I never got this working and no-one on PhpExcel forums or elsewhere seems to know anything about the error.

2) We need to be able to take data from TWO categories in the download: i.e. **category="1&2"** in the parameters.  Have not been able to find out if Export_It supports this but it seems not as it doesn't work.

So we need another solution. Has anyone successfully implemented PhpExcel as a stand-alone in EE? Are there any other modules or solutions you might recommend?

Comment: Hey segovius, I think the approach of using EE templates to generate the spreadsheet. There are some good answers in [What is the best method for exporting channel entries as a spreadsheet?](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/515/what-is-the-best-method-for-exporting-channel-entries-as-a-spreadsheet) as well as a helpful [comment by Issac](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/515/what-is-the-best-method-for-exporting-channel-entries-as-a-spreadsheet#comment638_517)

Comment: Whoops. Previous comment meant to say ...I think using EE templates _would work for you_

Comment: Great, Alex, thanks. That seems to work but there's one issue which is minor but probably should fix: in Safari Mac this method is appending .html to the .xls file.

Did you come across this? Anyway to remove it so the end-user doesn't have to?

Comment: Good point. Rob Sanchez's HTTP Header plugin can help with that. I added this as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One really flexible and simple shortcut to exporting a .xls spreadsheet of Channel data is to generate an html table using an ExpressionEngine template, save the page as a file, and then open the file with MS Excel.

1. Create a template (eg `export.group/index.html`)
2. Output all the necessary data using a `channel:entries` loop and any other necessary template tags.
3. Load this template on the front end in your browser (above example template would load at `example.com/export`)
4. Either save the webpage as a file and *manually* set the file extension to `.xls` or use the [HTTP Header](https://github.com/rsanchez/http_header) plugin to automatically force download and set the appropriate file extension for you.

Example template code including force download of `.xls` file:

```
{exp:http_header 
    content_disposition="attachment" 
    filename="myfile.xls" 
    content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
}
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Entry ID</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Author</th>
            <th>Created</th>
            <th>Updated</th>
            <th>Status</th>
            <th>Tool File</th>
            <th>Tool URL</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {exp:channel:entries
            channel="tools"
            disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination"
            dynamic="no"
            limit="999"
        }
            <tr>
                <td>{entry_id}</td>
                <td>{title}</td>
                <td>{author}</td>
                <td>{entry_date format="%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i"}</td>
                <td>{edit_date format="%Y-%m-%d-%H:%i"}</td>
                <td>{status}</td>
                <td>{tool_file}</td>
                <td>{tool_url}</td>
            </tr>
        {/exp:channel:entries}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Yeah I was essentially doing this but with PHP rather than Rob's plugin - tired both now but seems that Safari still appends the .html in ether case. I think it's a Safari thing as it doesn't happen with other browsers. 

One other thing re this is that it's not essentially a native .xsl file even when you remove the .html manually. You need .xslx for that but can't get that working at all.

Comment: I see what you mean. I updated my answer and added the `content_type` parameter to the HTTP Header tag. This seems to satisfy Safari in my test. The Safari-downloaded file has just .xls as the file extension and opens right up in Excel.

Comment: Great... that did it! I've marked your post as the answer. One thing about the file - though I can probably live with this - is that it seems to have no borders on the cells, basically is the borderless cells and info on a plain white background. No biggie though I guess. 

I'm also trying to get get the category ID here in the parameters from the url segment so the download can be dynamic but it seems this is not possible. I guess I should open another question for that though unless you know of a quick fix. Thanks for this!

Comment: That's a good point about the borders. I might have to experiment with that. I bet you can get the category bit to work, but I think you are right: a new question with some template code would be best.