# Setting a category from segment in .xls download template

Tags: categories, segments, export

We've set up a template to download an .xsl file of entries in a number of specific categories (with much help in [this SE thread](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/28558/download-to-excel-or-csv-solutions/28581)) - all works fine if we hardcode the category ID but if we tray to make the template dynamic by getting the category ID from the URL segment it fails (see below).

Is it possible to dynamically set the Category ID like this? Or any other way?

```
{exp:http_header 
    content_disposition="attachment" 
    filename="myfile.xls" 
    content_type="application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"
}
<table>
<tbody>
{exp:channel:entries channel="my channel" category="{segment_3}" disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination"
}
<tr>
<td>{title}</td>
<td>{field_one}</td>
<td>{field_two}</td>
</tr>
{/exp:channel:entries}
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: "It fails" how? Can you please, update your answer with more details?

Comment: Ah yes, if I hardcode it then it downloads the Excel file with all the correct data (minus cell borders - just un-bordered cells on a white background but that's ok) but if the Cat ID is taken via {segment_3} which is where the ID number is in the url, then it downloads the .xls file but it is blank containing no data.

Comment: I think i found the issue. Please, help me a little more. Does the URL used on the hard coded category test have a `segment_3`? Or, for the test, it just has the segments 1 and 2?

Comment: It's just one segment it's using - the last one Segment_3 - I'm always passing the third segment for the test

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work fine. You're just missing a [`dynamic="no"`](https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#dynamic) on your `channel:entries` tag.

Try it like this:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    channel="my channel" 
    category="{segment_3}" 
    disable="category_fields|member_data|pagination" 
    dynamic="no"
}
```

Comment: That's the one! Great!