# Exporting Products to a CSV

Tags: cartthrob, export, csv, product

Is there a way of exporting all products and data to a CSV file from carthrob expression engine v2.8.1?

Kind regards,

Dan

Comment: Both the answers below are great options. For a third option using template tags and EE templates check out this answer http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/532/22 (you'd use Cartthrob tags instead of Channel module tags).

Answer (score 2):

I don't know of any particular 3rd party add-ons that are crafted to specifically export Cart Throb data, but it's a pretty cut-and-dry process to output a MySQL table to CSV. You can use a tool like Sequel Pro (OS X) or MySQL Workbench (Windows, Linux) to select your data with a query and then save the query results as a CSV file.

If you require something easier to work with or more integrated with ExpressionEngine, there might be an add-on to help, but I personally don't know of one. Datagrab might have integration with Cart Throb. Hopefully someone else can chime in.

The process of crafting a PHP script or a full EE add-on to export MySQL tables is a pretty trivial development process. It might take some time to get right but it's not complex at all. Consider going for it (assuming you are a developer)!

Answer (score 2):

Try https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajw-export. I recently used it to export Store products.

Answer (score 0):

https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zeal-smart-export
is the best option to export data from channel without do any code or sql query.

Answer (score 0):

I second the use of EE tags and templates.

You don't have to worry about third-party module updates and support. You also can use the same method for exporting other content with any number of different tags attached including HTML, XML, etc.

We have even used that method to export content with Quark, InDesign and other publishing tags.